# Codeigniter Mongo db select query not working in nginx server

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, nginx

Recently I am using mongodb inside codeigniter in my apache server here that all working fine , below is my db connection and select query

```
$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://'.MONGO_HOST.'', array('username' => MONGO_USER, 'password' => MONGO_PASS, 'db'=> MONGO_DB ));
$db = $m->selectDB(MONGO_DB);

    $ops = array(
                 array(
                 '$match'=>array(
                 "datetime"=>array('$gte'=>$start,'$lte'=>$end)
                    )
                 ),
            array(
                '$group' => array("_id" => array("purchaseid" => '$purchaseid',"viewerid" => '$viewerid'),"total" => array('$sum' => 1))));

    $result = $db->collection_name->aggregate($ops);
```

above code working fine in my apache server and I get data from mongodb, the same code I tried to run in my nginx server,I get 500 internal server error,If I print $m in nginx server its show below reult,

```
MongoClient Object ( [connected] => 1 [status] => [server:protected] => [persistent:protected] => )
```

I my understand db connection enabled,but accessing collection shows 500 error,am not sure this is the issue,Need to configure any other dependencies for using mongo in nginx server, Anyone help to solve this problem

Comment: check this link. It might help you.
https://serverfault.com/questions/869452/setting-up-mongodb-behind-nginx

Comment: It should not make a difference as such. Only issue could be apache php.ini and fpm php.ini are not same. So that might be causing Mongo module not be to loaded. You can run a simple `phpinfo()` page and check that out